# Using @ViewChild in angular2

Tags: angular

Trying to use 2-way data-binding, local reference passed into a method & local reference using @ViewChild. But I'm not getting the desired output. Please find my code below & suggest

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

  serverElements = [{type: 'server', name: 'Test Server', content: 'This is test server', port: 4200}];

  onServerAdded(serverData: {serverName: string, serverContent: string, serverPort: number}) {
    this.serverElements.push({
    type: 'server',
    name: serverData.serverName,
    content: serverData.serverContent,
    port: serverData.serverPort,

      });
    }

    onBlueprintAdded(blueprintData: {serverName: string, serverContent: string, serverPort: number}) {
      this.serverElements.push({
        type: 'blueprint',
        name: blueprintData.serverName,
        content: blueprintData.serverContent,
        port: blueprintData.serverPort,

      });
    }

    onServerPortAdded(portData: {serverName: string, serverContent: string, serverPort: number}) {
      this.serverElements.push({
        type: 'port',
        name: portData.serverName,
        content: portData.serverContent,
        port: portData.serverPort,

    });
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <app-server-base (serverCreated)=" onServerAdded($event) " (blueprintCreated)=" onBlueprintAdded($event) " (serverPortAdded)=" onServerPortAdded($event)" (serverLocationAdded)=" onServerLocationAdded($event)">Loading...</app-server-base>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <app-server-element *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements" [element]="serverElement">Loading...</app-server-element>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

server-base.component.ts

```
export class ServerBaseComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() serverCreated = new EventEmitter<{serverName: string, serverContent: string, port: number}>();
  @Output() blueprintCreated = new EventEmitter<{serverName: string, serverContent: string, port: number}>();
  @Output() serverPortAdded = new EventEmitter<{serverName: string, serverContent: string, port: number}>();
  newServerName = '';
 // newServerContent = '';
  @ViewChild('portNumberInput') portNumberInput: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addServer(contentInput: HTMLInputElement) {
    this.serverCreated.emit({serverName: this.newServerName,
      serverContent: contentInput.value,
      port: this.portNumberInput.nativeElement.value});
    }

    addBlueprint(contentInput: HTMLInputElement) {
      this.blueprintCreated.emit({serverName: this.newServerName,
        serverContent: contentInput.value,
        port: this.portNumberInput.nativeElement.value});
    }

    addServerPort(contentInput: HTMLInputElement) {
      this.serverPortAdded.emit({serverName: this.newServerName,
        serverContent: contentInput.value,
        port: this.portNumberInput.nativeElement.value});
    }
}
```

server-base.component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h4> Add Server Details </h4>
        <label> Server Name </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerName">
        <label> Server Content </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" #serverContentInput>
        <label> Server Port </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" #portNumberInput>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addServer(serverContentInput)"> Add Server </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addBlueprint(serverContentInput)"> Add Server Blueprint </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addServerPort(serverContentInput)"> Add Server Port </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

server-element.component.ts

```
export class ServerElementComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() element: {type: string, name: string, content: string, port: number};
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

server-element.component.html

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{ element.name}}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>
            <strong *ngIf="element.type === 'server'" style="color: red">{{ element.content }}</strong>
            <em *ngIf="element.type === 'blueprint'">{{ element.content }}</em>
        </p>
        <p> <strong>{{ element.port }} </strong></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the "desired output"? Are you getting an error? Is something  not displayed correctly? Is the binding not working? Please also include a question in your question.

Comment: what do you want

Comment: your `portNumberInput ` should be component then `Viewchild` could detect though I didn't try use `#portNumberInput` to make it. By the way, explain precise.

Comment: @ViewChild ('portNumberInput') value is not getting displayed when I input some value under Server Port text area on the HTML page. And I'm not getting any error either. FYI, the initial value of 4200 (set in app.component.ts) is displayed on the HTML page load.

Comment: @DevilWhoCodes Your comment should be an edit of your question.

Comment: @Rach Chen Can you explain your suggestion.

Comment: @haindl All I want is to figure out why #portNumberInput reference's value which is entered through Server Port text area is not displayed on the HTML page when Add Server/Add Server Blueprint button is clicked?